# Return an integer value when pattern matching type value in F#

Tags: function, f#, pattern-matching

```
let Greeting name = 
    match name with
    | "Joe" | "Bob" | "Ray" -> "Hello"
    | "Miguel" | "Jose" -> "Hola"
    | _ -> "Don't know what to say"
```

This pattern matching function works perfectly fine with strings, but when I attempt to convert it to compare custom type values visual studio says the function is unfinished, even though the syntax is exactly the same.

```
type Suit = Spades | Clubs | Hearts | Diamonds
type Rank = Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King
type Card = { suit: Suit; rank: Rank}

let cardValue (card:Card) = 
    match card.rank with
    | Ace -> 1
    | Two -> 2
    | Three -> 3
    | Four -> 4
    | Five -> 5
    | Six -> 6
    | Seven -> 7
    | Eight -> 8
    | Nine -> 9
    | Ten | Jack | Queen | King -> 10
    | _ -> 0
```

Visual studio suggested adding an explicit result, so I added a wildcard (even though it should be unnecessary because card objects can't be created without a rank set afaik) but the error persists.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I load your card-matching code in Visual Studio, it tells me that the `_ -> 0` line will never be matched. If I remove the wildcard, it gives no errors -- but if I then remove one of the matches (like the `Six -> 6` line), I'm informed that the match is incomplete: "For example, the value 'Six' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s)."

Comment: When you say that "Visual Studio suggested adding an explicit result", what is the *precise* error message that you're getting? And which part(s) of the code produced that error message (i.e., where did the wavy underline(s) show up)? Also, which version of Visual Studio and of the Visual F# Tools are you using?

Comment: @rmunn i'm using visual studio 2017 enterprise, and f# core 4.4.1.0, the error it gives me is "The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result." and the code that triggers it is the 'let' at the start of the cardValue function.

Comment: Ah. That error has nothing to do with the `match` expression. It's just that a `let` statement *may not* be the last expression in a function. I'll write an answer with more details. But while I'm doing so, could you paste your actual code? Because the code that you've shown so far is entirely correct and *could not* produce that error message; there must be at least one thing you've omitted. And I bet your actual code looks like `let something = match card.rank with ...`, and you omitted the `let something =` part to make the example code simpler.

Comment: OHHH shit. Yeah, I've declared the cardValue function inside a 'calculate value of hand' function, and the return for the score was before the match.

Comment: In that case, the answer I'm writing may be unnecessary (because you've probably just figured out your problem)... but I'll finish it anyway for the sake of anyone else who finds this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're getting, you've said in the comments, is the following one:

> The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.

This has nothing to do with your `match` expression, and you can safely remove the `_ -> 0` line. You're seeing that error because somewhere you have a `let` statement inside a code block that is not followed by another expression. I.e., this code is not legal:

```
let f x =
    let result = x + 5
```

All functions in F# must return a value, and the `let` statement is one of the VERY few things in F# that is a *statement*, not an *expression*. `let` **does not return a value**. So when you're inside a code block, you **MUST** follow up a `let` statement with some other expression, so that something that *returns a value* is the last expression of the function. I.e.,:

```
let f x =
    let result = x + 5
    result
```

This is legal.

Note that this does *not* apply at the module level. Modules are "containers" that contain values, and do not have a value themselves. (They get compiled into static classes, basically). So this is fine:

```
module Foo =
    let f x = x + 1
    let value = 26
```

It is perfectly okay (in fact, it's normal) for a `let` statement to be the last line in a module. But it may not be the last line in a *function* (or any other code block), because functions must return a value.